# window.open invocation does not work inside of bootstrap modal in chrome

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

In chrome, window.open inside of bootstrap modal doesn't work. This is true even if the window.open is triggered in same thread as the button click that triggers it

Comment: Where's the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: The minimal complete and verifiable is a recommendation. It's not mandatory. I didnt attach one because there is so much code to attach

Comment: Not sure what sort of help or answer you expect if people can't reproduce a problem and the problem description given has such little debugging information and not a single line of code provided. How much code do you need to recreate this problem? The window object is the same regardless of browser

Answer (score 1):

There is no magic in modal - this just usual code. Just several divs are added.

```
window.open() works as expected
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/LRnO401jCiCRlHFQn2jJ?p=preview

Comment: in other words... ***can't reproduce issue***